# Using powershell to identify process ID, Name, and arguments used to start

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, process, command-line-arguments

**My Issue:**

I need to identify the process ID of a specific process that is running. My problem is, I run a lot of processes through cscript.exe, so identifying the ID for a ton of "cscript.exe" processes isn't very helpful. I need to see the ID and the arguments that were passed to cscript to better manage these.

**What I've done so far:**

I use the following to identify the start times, and ID's of my cscript.exe processes:

```
Get-Process -Name cscript -IncludeUsername |select starttime, Id, UserName, ProcessName
```

This works out for me a lot of times, because in this case the jobs are few and have very specific start times. But now that I'm running a few of these at similar start times, I need to clean up my act when it comes to positively identifying these tasks.

In my search to get the arguments used to start my cscript.exe processes, I've learned about `Get-WmiObject` and I'm currently using it this way:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'cscript.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine| format-list
```

This is pretty good, I'm able to see cscript.exe, and the arguments that were passed to it. However, I still need the process ID.

I've attempted to add `ID` to my `Select-Object` command above, but it results in an empty field being returned alongside the `CommandLine` results.

**My question:**

I'm not very PowerShell savvy. With that said, I'm looking for help combining these two system queries. **What can I do with PowerShell to return the process name, arguments, and ID?** If possible, it would also be nice to see the start time included in this, but that isn't as important as the properties listed in bold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, I find my answer shortly after giving up and asking.

Not being too familiar with PowerShell, I dropped `CommandLine` from `Select-Object CommandLine` just to see what I would get, and I got *everything.* This includes the process Id. Instead if trying `ID`, I should have tried `ProcessId`. That was the ticket.

So, the final solution was:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'cscript.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine, ProcessId| format-list
```